# Can I post a message in Microsoft Teams general posts and be able to see it in power apps?

Tags: microsoft-teams, powerapps, powerapps-formula

Would it be possible to be able to see the general posts from a Microsoft Teams channel to my custom power apps app?
Example:
I have created a Teams channel:
[My Teams channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo4f1.png) and would like to see everything that is being added there, to my custom app, maybe with a field named "Posts":
[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSPkh.png)
If a new field is not an option, then is there any other way to see the posts in my custom app?

I can't find a way to create a field that will connect to the Teams Channel Posts and brings all the comments to my custom app.
I would expect a connector making this job?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

1. Create a Power Automate flow with Power Apps V2 trigger
2. Use 'Teams/Get messages' action to get the content from the teams channel.
3. Initialize a text variable
4. Use 'Append to text variable' to combine plain text information from the messages. Add separators too.
5. Use 'Respond to Power Apps' action and return the combined text
6. In the app, use Split() to separate the messages again.